# How can i write unit test for Azure Function App written in c#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure, nunit, azure-functions

I have to write Unit test for azure function based app in Nunit3 as these function are developed in c# ?

The confusion is that , normal code is tested by creating mock object , then call method and then assert , but i am unable to do in case of Azure function as it has only method Run().

What are best way to tackle this problem ?

Comment: What's the problem to call `Run` from your test? You'd need to add an example to make this question more specific.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] of the function to be tested and what you have tried so far. That way we can see where you went wrong and provide some assistance is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the logic you want to test in a method in a separate class, that way you can write tests for that class as you normally would. Then in your Azure Function's Run method you can instantiate that class and call the method.